# How to use iphone as a gateway in SMSLib?

Tags: java, iphone, gateway, smslib

I want to use **SMSLib** in a Java application in order to send an **SMS** to my iPhone without using an external gateway, So, i want to deal with the phone as the gateway and make it receive the message, node that I'm considering the **GSM** of the mobile as the modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access any of iOS SMS settings nor the messages. Java is also not support natively on iOS. It is also not possible to do any low level GSM calls like SMS.

If you want to send a SMS in iOS you will need to use the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)